# The meaning of the phrase "end all to be all"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the phrase *end all to be all*? For example:

> Some people believe that PPE is **end all to be all.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *the be all and end all of*

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/be+all+and+end+all

> The quintessential or all-important element: "Not that the more
>   spectacular athleticism is the be all and end all of free skating.
>   Spins . . . and intricate step sequences are also important" (Howard
>   Bass).